# ui: define inside a h :form

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have a template with 3 ui:insert tags's to display in different places. on my create userpage i have this:

```
<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.CreateEmployeesTitle}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="body">
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateEmployeesLabel_businessUnitId}" for="businessUnitId" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="businessUnitId" value="#{employeesController.selected.businessUnitId}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{businessUnitController.items}" var="a" itemLabel="#{a.description}" itemValue="#{a.id}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateEmployeesLabel_employeeTypesId}" for="employeeTypesId" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="employeeTypesId" value="#{employeesController.selected.employeeTypesId}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{employeeTypesController.items}" var="b" itemLabel="#{b.description}" itemValue="#{b.id}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateEmployeesLabel_employeeManagersEmployeeNo}" for="employeeManagersEmployeeNo" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="employeeManagersEmployeeNo" value="#{employeesController.selected.employeeManagersEmployeeNo}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{employeeManagersController.items}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.name}" itemValue="#{c.employeeNo}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <ui:define name="li1">
                        <h:commandLink action="#{employeesController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateEmployeesSaveLink}" styleClass="auto-style4" />
            </ui:define>
                <ui:define name="li2">
                        <h:commandLink action="#{employeesController.prepareList}" value="#{bundle.CreateEmployeesShowAllLink}" immediate="true" styleClass="auto-style4"/>
                </ui:define>

            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

So now my links aren't rendered, but when i remove the ui:define tags at the bottom it works, the reason i want it this way is because the commandlinks will be on a right column. what can i replace ui:define with so that my commandlinks still work in my right column?

Here is an example of my template:

```
<h:body>
        <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <header id="header">
                            <h1><a href="#" id="logo" ><img src="../resources/images/btttr.png" alt="logoo" class="left" /></a></h1>
                            <nav id="nav">
                                <ui:insert name="heads"></ui:insert>
                            </nav>
                        </header>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row main-row">
                    <div class="8u">
                        <section class="left-content">
                            <div>
                                <ui:insert name="pagetitle">Default Title</ui:insert>
                                <br/>
                                <br/>
                            </div>
                            <ui:insert name="body">Default Body</ui:insert>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                    <div class="4u">
                        <section>
                            <ul class="small-image-list">
                                <li>
                                    <li> 
                                        <ui:insert name="li1"></ui:insert></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <ui:insert name="li2"></ui:insert></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <ui:insert name="li3"></ui:insert></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <ui:insert name="li4"></ui:insert></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <ui:insert name="li5"></ui:insert></li>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
```

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: basically what i'm asking is how can i let my commandlinks display in my right column while its in the form?

Comment: Template added to post

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest an `<ui:define>` for the same template inside another `<ui:define>`. This isn't making any sense. It won't magically change the template composition. Instead, the template itself has to be modified as such that the body and links end up in the same form.

One way would be to move `<h:form>` from the template client to `<div class="row main-row">`. Another way would be to extend the template with another template specifically for forms.